# C Makefile from "learncodethehardway" not working

Tags: c, makefile, ubuntu-14.04

I am having an issue learning C. I was using a website called learncodethehardway, and I was on this page: http://c.learncodethehardway.org/book/ex2.html . I have looked all over the web, and i cannot find the answer to my problem. I am supposed to run the code;

```
CFLAGS=-Wall -g

clean:
    rm -f ex1
```

but no matter what I do, I get these errors:

> "no type or storage class" for CFLAGS
>   "'Wall' undeclared(not in a function)"
>   "g undeclared here (not in a function)"
>   "error: expected ',' or ';' before 'clean'

As the instructions say: i should do the command: 'run clean', but all this does is give me the response: 'make: *** No rule to make target 'clean'. Stop.'

If anyone can make sense of this and help me out, that would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You should have a file 'Makefile' with that content and run 'make', that will find the Makefile.

Comment: You seem to be trying to compile the makefile (your above code) with the c compiler. Put the above code into a file called `Makefile`, then write your c code in a different file, e.g. `ex1.c` or `ex2.c`, then type `make ex1` or `make ex2`, respectively.

Comment: Perhaps you should look for a course called “learncodetheeasyway”.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not code that you are supposed to run. That is the content of a file called `Makefile` that is interpreted by a program called `make` that will follow those instructions and will build your application. So, create that file, paste that code into it and run `make` and it should work.